# C#: SSML syntax for Chinese pinyin using Microsoft Azure Text to Speech API

Tags: c#, azure, cjk, ssml

I have developed an C# Windows apps uisng Azure "Text to Speech" API but for Chinese, I have not figured out how to insert pinyin strings in SSML format that the Azure API can interpret. I'm aware that Amazon Polly can interpre the following SSML code and I'm just trying to do the same thing with Azure.

```
<speak>
    你说 <phoneme alphabet="x-amazon-pinyin" ph="bo2">薄</phoneme>。 
    我说 <phoneme alphabet="x-amazon-pinyin" ph="bao2">薄</phoneme>。
</speak>
```

Should I just create a SSML code with other phoneme options such as

- ipa – International Phonetic Alphabet
- sapi – Speech API Phone Set

to make this happen with Azure?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks like I can use the sapi option for pinyin like "你说 <phoneme alphabet="sapi" ph="bo 2">薄</phoneme>。." Still, any comment or suggestion will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You could summarize your solution as an answer.